# How to parse this command-line arguments in Python argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

I want to parse my command-line arguments like:

```
python main.py Option_1 -r ... -m ...
python main.py Option_2 -r ... -m ...
```

I require my first argument be a string, and it must be either `Option_1`or `Option_2`. Everything after the first argument are normal option/value pairs.

I can't seem to find how to do it with the argparse library. I can easily grab the option/value pairs, but how to parse `Option_1` and `Option_2`, they don't have a flag like `-r` and `-m`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the argument I want from `sys.argv` before parsing works.

```
sys.argv.pop(1)  
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a positional argument with choices:

```
parser.add_argument('pos', choices=['Option_1','Option_2'], help=...)
```

It will accept one of these 2 as the first string, but it doesn't actually have to be first.  One or more of the `-r` and `-m` arguments will be accepted before this first `positional`.